# pyspark code failing with error An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame.apply. list#5451 []

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, aws-glue-spark

I am writing aws glue job (pyspark code) using SQL Transformation. I am getting error with scala.MatchError: list#5252 [] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ListQuery. There is one table like tbl1 when i exclude this table from query it is working fine but as soon as tbl1 is used above error is throwing. Source and Target both are Redshift.

If anyone explain meaning of this error would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Please let me know if any description needed in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scala.MatchError: list#5252 [] - This error refers to issues while joining two or more tables where one of column is not able to match the pattern/value of another table.
To fix this, check SQL query and update joins.

In SQL Transformation (AWS GLUE)
Query with NOT IN can be executed without any issues in AWS Glue. In case (NOT IN) fails, try to run query in parts.